# Finding when a sum is convergant

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to show for which values of $p$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges/diverges using only Raabe's test.
I tried to check but I always got the following result which ended up not helping at all:

$L=lim_{n\to\infty} n(1-\frac{\frac{1}{n^{p+1}}}{\frac{1}{n^{p}}})=lim_{n\to\infty} n(1-\frac{n^p}{n^{p+1}})=lim_{n\to\infty} n(1-\frac{1}{n})$

And that doesn't even have $p$ in it!
What should I do?

Comment: The variable of the serie is $n$, not $p$.

Comment: Oh you're right!

Answer (score 0):

That means:

$L=lim_{n\to\infty} n(1-\frac{\frac{1}{(n+1)^p}}{\frac{1}{n^{p}}})=lim_{n\to\infty} n(1-\frac{n^p}{(n+1)^p})=lim_{n\to\infty} n(1-(\frac{n}{n+1})^p)$

And then what?